# Reviewing Suggested Edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just received a link to:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/74207

It appears to be in regard to a question I asked some time ago.

I am not clear as to what (if anything) I am supposed to do with it.

This is the first link of this sort which I have received.

Can someone clue me in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, nothing. The community dealt with the edit itself (rejecting it) and all good.

Comment: Thanks. It was very confusing. It was hard to tell if I had stepped in something again or if it was another user's turn. It would be great if somewhere near the to it said something like "No action required" or "This is not your fault" (second one is meant to be humorous).

Answer (score 3):

If any of your posts (questions or answers) are edited, you will receive a message letting you know. If the user who edited the post has less than 2k reputation, you will be given the chance to approve or reject the edit.

These are part of how the site works and nothing to worry about. When you receive such a notification, just check the edited post and make sure that the change does not introduce errors or is otherwise inappropriate. If it is, you can roll back to the previous version or fix it manually. If it looks good, you can approve it (if need it) or just ignore it.